# Included File Gets Me Undefined Variables

Tags: php, include

Couldn't find an answer that solves my codes issue.

file.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['season1'])) {

    $season1 = $_GET['season1'];
    $url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/'.$season1.'/episodes?season=1';

    $imdb_content = file_get_contents($url);
    $html = str_get_html($imdb_content);

    //Grabbed Content
    $resultarray = array();
    foreach($html->find('strong a[itemprop="name"]') as $results) {
        $resultarray[] = $results;
    }

    echo $resultarray[0];
    echo $resultarray[1];

} 
else {
        header("Location: ../");
}
```

index.php:

```
    include("http://example.com/file.php?season1=".urlencode($imdbid));
(...)
<div class="row">
<div class="tech-spec-element col-xs-20 col-sm-10 col-md-5"> <span title="Episode 1"></span>1 - <?= $resultarray[0]; ?>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="tech-spec-element col-xs-20 col-sm-10 col-md-5"> <span title="Episode 2"></span>2 - <?= $resultarray[1]; ?>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="tech-spec-element col-xs-20 col-sm-10 col-md-5"> <span title="Episode 3"></span>3 - <?= $resultarray[2]; ?>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="tech-spec-element col-xs-20 col-sm-10 col-md-5"> <span title="Episode 4"></span>4 - <?= $resultarray[3]; ?>
<div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I know the file.php is being loaded fine as it gives me its output but when I try and use `$resultarray[0]`; it just doesn't work and say it's undefined.

Comment: What's `$html->find` giving you?

Comment: Basically matched html as in the episode name

Comment: I dont think the problem is the array as when I go directly to the url it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Are you including `file.php` from it's web url? Why? Are they on different servers? If so, you are receiving just output from that file, you will not have access to any of it's variables. To have access to included script's variables, you must include it so that it is executed locally.

So, for example, if both scripts are on the same server, in the same directory, in your `index.php` you can do:

```
$season = urlencode($imdbid);
include 'file.php';
```

And in your `file.php`:

```
if(isset($season)) {
    $season1 = $season;
    //...the rest of your code
```

Comment: Yeah, but when i do ../ urls its for some reason not finding it. Like this is the exact url I have just different directory names and is the exact smae amount of directorys:
Index.php is at http://example.com/1/2/tt1865718/index.php
And then file.php is at http://example.com/1/2/file.php
So i try do include('../../file.php'); but apparently it wont be found.

Comment: For paths which you gave in your comment, you need to traverse up 1 level, not two levels, so you should remove one `../` from `include`, it should be: `include('../file.php');`

Comment: Oops on file.php the directory i called 2 is soemthing else so like 3 so going back ../ once wont work

Comment: Okay I can confirm this works to get the right url: include "../../functions/imdb.php?season1=tt1865718"; but it seems like when i try to use that in the include tag it wont work it just says its not found

Comment: it will include fine if its in the same directory but I simply cant do that

Comment: You can't add query string (in your example: `?season1=tt1865718`) to include statement. It will not work, and it will tell you file is not found. Instead, you should declare a variable in your `index.php` and use that variable in your `file.php` (take a look at my answer above). You can also use $_SESSION, or $_GET, or any other globals to pass the value.

Comment: it seems like its being foudn just by doing include("http://crime.pw/torrents/functions/imdb.php?season1=".$imdbid); if I turn on allow_url_include = On in my php.ini but its still saying resultarray is undefined

Comment: Again, as I said, to access included file variables, it must be executed locally. Read about `include` and `variable scope`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: but how do I tell it to basically load season1=$imdbid?

Comment: hmm ok I put global $resultarray; in the file that created the array at the top then I did a simple var_dump($resultarray); but its outputting null doesnt that mean the array has nothing? Why does it have nothign when it gets transfered over?